# Why CTRL + click on some flutter widgets in android studio doesn't show the source dart code?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I have recently started with flutter. When I CTRL + click on a flutter widget in android studio to see the code behind the widget, instead of the dart code for the widget, the IDE shows me something strange.
For example, here I've CTRL + clicked on a FloatingActionButton() to see the its code. Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix it?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

changing flutter channel worked for me,

try this command
`flutter channel dev`

Edit:
actually after struggling with this problem i found out it has nothing to do with flutter, it's android studio issue, 
Just delete

.gradle

.idea

build

folders from your project and reopen the project. and it will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

use Ctrl + B to navigate to source code, code declaration and usage